# Entity Framework 5 SqlQuery Slow Materializing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am using EF 5, POCO objects, and SqlQuery.  The materializing of objects is very slow about 20 seconds.  If I run the SQL query using sql management studio the query runs in about 2 seconds.  (example this.context.mytable.SqlQuery(query).AsNoTracking.ToList())

I was previously using this exact same SQL query with EF 4, Generated Entities and ExecuteStoreQuery.  The materializing of objects was not as slow about 10 seconds.

Why the performance difference using POCO's?  I have already tried using ExecuteStoreQuery from DbContext using the POCO's with the same slow (20 seconds) results.

Any Ideas?

In advance, thank you!

**Update:**

1. entity classes:
   Two entity classes, one is a base class. Between the two there are about 27 columns/properties with most being on the base class.
2. number of objects in selection result:
   About 75K.
3. store query being executed:
   The query is a select (columns) from view where (1=1)
4. API being used (DbContext or ObjectContext)
   In the EF 5/POCO scenario I am using DbContext.
   In the EF 4/Generated entities scenario I am using ObjectContext.

   **When using EF 5/DbContext I have also tried accessing the (lower level) ObjectContext and ExecuteStoreQuery method, that gave the same slow results as with DbContext SqlQuery.

Comment: Please, provide more information - entity classes, number of objects in selection result, store query being executed, API being used (`DbContext` or `ObjectContext`).

Answer (score 0):

False alarm... ended up being a small amount of reflection in the poco's that degraded performance when materializing many objects.